# All post of child category not in top category

Tags: categories, archives

i have data category:

```
- About us
-- Sub 1 about us
-- Sub 2 about us
```

In Categor `About us` a has add post : `About us 1, About us 2, About us 3....`

In Sub category `Sub 1 about us` i has add list post: `Sub 1 about us 1, Sub 1 about us 2...`

In Sub category `Sub 2 about us` i has add list post: `Sub 2 about us 1, Sub 2 about us 2...`

How to:

In Archive Category `About us` echo list post of `Sub 1 about us & Sub 2 about us` not show `About us 1, About us 2, About us 3....` in category `About us`

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you talk post query, you can use function [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). You can search about it on this site and find good approach. Try it, and if you have problem, please add your code, and be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do?

```
  $cat = 'About us';
  $tax = 'category';
  $cat_id = get_cat_ID($cat);
  $category = get_term_children($cat_id, $tax);
  $pre = '';
  foreach ($category as $sub)
  {
      $cat_list .= $pre . $sub;
      $pre = ', ';
  }
  query_posts(array( 'cat' => $cat_list, 'posts_per_page' => 1000));
  echo '<ul>';
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
  endwhile;
  echo '</ul>';
```